# overflow auto is not making the div scrollable bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have two divs wrapped in one div the first div contains a table and the second contains buttons. I want to make the div that have the table scrollable so I used overflow-auto on that div and it's not working I think the problem might be in the other parent div using flex-frow-1 but couldn't figure it out
here is my code :

```
<div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column">

    <div class="d-flex flex-column col-12 col-xl-5 col-lg-5 col-md-5 h-100 bg-primary">
      <fieldset class="border border-2 border-bottom-0 rounded-top">
        <legend class="w-auto px-2 float-none mb-0 fs-5 text-start">
          label
        </legend>
      </fieldset>
      <div class="flex-grow-1 border border-2 border-top-0 rounded-bottom">
        <div class="rounded overflow-auto h-92">
          <table
            class="table table-hover text-center rounded p-0 m-0 overflow-auto"
          >
            <thead class="bg-primary text-white">
              <tr>
                <th class="fw-bold">name</th>
                <th class="fw-bold">age</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
             
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
              <tr class="">
                <td>marwan</td>
                <td class="text-danger">22</td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
        <div class="col-8 d-flex justify-content-around mt-2">
          <button class="py-1 px-0 btn primary-button col-5">button1</button
          ><button class="py-1 px-0 btn primary-button col-5">button 2</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

what I want to achieve is the following :
have a div that takes a specific height lets say 90vh
inside that have a div that takes 100% of the 90vh div
inside that have 2 divs the first is of height 90% of the 100% div and when items inside it overflow it handles this by making the div scrollable
and the other one takes the remaining height

Answer (score 0):

use boatstrap v4 (v4.5.2 Work 100%)

and give height less then the content height for the table container (div with overflow auto)